# Prevent event listener from been execute in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, dom-events

I want to build a Google Chrome extension to sync all my bookmarks across Chrome so I have attached an event listener to [onCreated](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/bookmarks.html#event-onCreated);

```
chrome.bookmarks.onCreated.addListener(function (id, bookmark) {
    console.log('Hey bookmark created ' + id);
});
```

The idea is that when the user creates a new bookmark this `onCreated` event listener sends a JSON object to a server via an AJAX request stating that a bookmark has been created.

If the server then returns a JSON object which indicates that the new bookmark should be created on the browser I don't need the `onCreated` event listener to be executed.

Basically, the idea is that the event listener should only be triggered if a bookmark has been manually created by the user and *not* programmatically.

For example, the event listener should not be executed when if a bookmark is created using the following command;

```
chrome.bookmarks.create({
   parentId: '648',
   title: 'Google Folder'
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using Chrome's sync feature? chrome://settings/syncSetup

Comment: Yes , I'm currently using Chrome "Sync Feature". but I want to build the extension so that I in future I can build extension for firefox and opera (If permitted) to sync my bookmarks across all browsers.

Comment: If that's what you're looking for I highly recommend you use the already established [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) browser add-ons.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of Xmarks But I recently found a major bug in Xmark as it lack intellengence to detect that duplicate bookmark exists(If something goes wrong) they have mention there limitation in one of there blog I dont seem to have the link now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to be able to pause `chrome.bookmarks.onCreated` while you are creating bookmarks programmatically. There is no clean way of doing it afaik, as Chrome API doesn't provide a way of removing event listeners, only adding.

I would try to make some global switch probably:

```
var listenerEnabled = true;
chrome.bookmarks.onCreated.addListener(function (id, bookmark) {
    if(listenerEnabled) {
        console.log('Hey bookmark created ' + id);
    }
});

function createBookmark() {
    listenerEnabled = false;
    chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId: '648',title: 'Google Folder'}, function() {
        //enable with delay in case listener fires late
        setTimeout(function() {
            listenerEnabled = true;
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

Another way would be marking bookmarks created programattically (by appending something to title for example), and then inside the listener you can detect them and remove this mark.

Comment: Ohh , This is ugly .Is there no other specific way to do this a more cleaner and better

Comment: @Viren I can't think of one, maybe someone else would.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to prevent the user from manually adding a bookmark.

If you are wanting to keep the browser's bookmarks in sync with the server then you should only really need to ensure the following;

1. All bookmarks on the server exist in the browser
2. Any modifications to bookmarks on the server should be reflected in the browser (e.g. removal, hierarchy)
3. Any bookmarks added to the browser are added to the server

Chrome already prevents users from creating a bookmark twice so you shouldn't need to perform this check but only notify your server which should add it to the database if it doesn't already exist there.

Bookmark syncing is relatively easy but you need to get your use cases and logic down on paper before you try and code this or it won't succeed.

Points 1 & 2 can be managed by periodically checking the server for updates. Point 3 you've already covered but the server needs to do the logic instead of the extension.

Comment: No No No ,I do not intend to prevent user from manually adding bookmark . The Idea is when the user create a bookmark using browser (by clicking on star icon) the "oncreated" listener would get executed and the json object of the newly created bookmark would be sent to the server , but If the server return the json object of bookmark that need to created on the browser(which is there is in server, but not on browser) then I dont need the onCreated Listener to be executed since the onCreated Listener needn't need to sent  bookmark json as it already there on server.

Comment: So I need is Preventing the "onCreated" Listener to execute when the bookmark is created programmatically.

Comment: It still sounds like you're trying to do 1 to 2 server calls when all you need is 1. Instead of checking if it's there and then sending it again if it's not. However, why not just send it once to the server where it will decide if it needs to be created or not?

Comment: At first when the sync Is done all the bookmark in browser sent to the server (say from machine-1 to server). Now I sync machine-2 to the server so the all the bookmark on the server is created on the browser on machine-2. Now It happen to create a bookmark on my machine-1 the sync succeed and the json bookmark of only newly created json would be sent to the server now whenever machine-2 connect to the server again only the newly created bookmark would be sent to machine-2 by the server(stating that the following bookmark need to be created on browser)

Comment: so the bookmark would be created  by the extension by the following code chrome.bookmarks.create({}) so I dont need the chrome.bookmarks.onCreated.addListener to be executed as the event contain code to sent(an ajax request) the json data to the server with the newly created bookmark (Which Is not required If bookmark is created programmatically as It is already present in server)

Answer (score 0):

Although the above solution will work, Boris Smus at google groups found another way to do the same thing:

```
var myListener = function(...) {...};
chrome.bookmarks.onCreated.addListener(myListener);
// Remove temporarily
chrome.bookmarks.onCreated.removeListener(myListener);
// Add again...
```

This removes the listener when you need to programmatically create a bookmark/folder, and re-adds it when you are ready.

I just tested and used this solution in my code. Many thanks to Boris Smus, at

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-extensions/fKYpINyqs1k

It would be preferable to able to do a programmatic create that does not trigger an event, or rather be able to do attach events only to user-specific actions. However, the solutions here will do for now.